# How to make OpenVPN's traffic go through its own interface, not default router's one?

Tags: openvpn

I set up an OpenVPN server on linux/Debian. It is supposed to be a virtual network for gaming purposes ONLY. It means that I want to keep their usual traffic to go through their default routers and direct only gaming traffic through OpenVPN's connection.
Here's the **Server's config**:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

**Client's config**:

```
client
dev tap
proto udp
remote <MY_SERVER'S_IP> 1194 #CHANGEME
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
ca ca.crt
cert client3.crt
key client3.key
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 3
mute 20
```

All my clients are behind NAT, with local subnets of 192.168.1.0/24 or 192.168.0.0/24.
As a client ( Win10 ) I can successfully connect to the server. At least OpenVPN's GUI box pops up and says it's connected. But I can't even ping the server (10.8.0.1) as all the traffic goes through the default route of 192.168.0.1.
Here is the **route -4 print** command output before connecting to the OpenVPN server.

```
===========================================================================
Список интерфейсов
 23...d8 97 ba 08 5d 16 ......Qualcomm Atheros AR8172/8176/8178 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)
 11...00 ff 55 13 9e 5f ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 30...12 10 b3 ed e0 6c ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #5
 22...22 10 b3 ed e0 6c ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #6
 21...42 10 b3 ed e0 6c ......Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter #2
  8...30 10 b3 ed e0 6c ......Qualcomm Atheros AR956x Wireless Network Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
Сетевой адрес           Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс  Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.14     55
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.0.14    311
     192.168.0.14  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.14    311
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.14    311
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.0.14    311
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.14    311
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Отсутствует
```

And the **route -4 print** output after successful connecting:

```
===========================================================================
Список интерфейсов
 23...d8 97 ba 08 5d 16 ......Qualcomm Atheros AR8172/8176/8178 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)
 11...00 ff 55 13 9e 5f ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 30...12 10 b3 ed e0 6c ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #5
 22...22 10 b3 ed e0 6c ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #6
 21...42 10 b3 ed e0 6c ......Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter #2
  8...30 10 b3 ed e0 6c ......Qualcomm Atheros AR956x Wireless Network Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
Сетевой адрес           Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс  Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.14     55
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.8.0.2    281
         10.8.0.2  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.2    281
       10.8.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.2    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.0.14    311
     192.168.0.14  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.14    311
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.14    311
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.8.0.2    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.0.14    311
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.2    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.14    311
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Отсутствует
```

I have tried to experiment with setting different **metric** to 0.0.0.0 or 10.8.0.0 route but to NO extent.
**tracert.exe 10.8.0.1** still goes through 192.168.0.1.

```
$>tracert 10.8.0.1

Трассировка маршрута к 10.8.0.1 [10.8.0.1]
с максимальным числом прыжков 30:

  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  rt [192.168.0.1]
  2    15 ms    14 ms    12 ms
--SNIPPED----
```

*If any additional info is required I will update this post.*

Comment: Your configuration is correct and the routing table is correct. The metric only matters if two routes have the same specificity. How are you deducing that `tracert` goes through `192.168.0.1`?

Comment: Posting the openvpn connection logs from the client and the server might be helpful.

Comment: @DanielB, updated the initial post.
To gmelis, logs at what level? I will add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apears, that setting `dev tun` to `dev tap` in **server's config** solved the problem. Haven't tested it yet, but **ping** works in both directions.